# Why does Angular read bound field/property twice?

Tags: angular, binding

Given the following Angular component, its field `property` is read twice per render:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'why-twice',
  template: `<button (click)="handler()">re-render</button> {{property}}`
})
export class WhyTwice {
  get property() {
    console.log('get property') // This will be printed 2x
    return 0
  }
  handler() {}
}
```

[Run this on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcdmzf)

**Why** is this the case? Would it not be sufficient to read it only once?

*I'm using Angular 7*

Comment: This is because angular does two checks in every change detection in  the development build, check it in production build, you will get one

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have now read that blog post and it answers my question fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When angular runs in development node. It runs twice every change detection cycle,  that's because to avoid you from further bugs. If you write something like this

```
Get property() { ret Date.now()}
```

And you cick change detection cycle it will check this value first, then rerenders  all changes, and check everything again to assure, that nothing was wrong, but on this time the property value will be different, so the case is property value is different and the view has different value rendered, so it thros expressionChanged error.
In production checks run only once per cycle, so you won't get any error

Answer (score -1):

Angular have very hectic change detection method.
In development angular have ChangeDetectionStrategy is default which check the change in all model property.
And in your situation,

```
 get property() {
    console.log('get property')
    return 0
  }
```

**getter** take value on click which detect change by angular, along with value is also getting return which also a change detection.